# Branch.io integration with Adwords

Tags: ads, google-ads-api, branch.io

I have a problem integrating branch.io with google Adwords. Although I've made all required steps and branch.io says that integration works fine, conversions in google Adwords don't match to conversions in branch.io and don't match with conversions in Google play. On the screenshot you can see that the difference is huge. I've tried to reauthenticate, to turn on and off the conversions in Adwords, but nothing helps. The support is responding once per week and is not useful at all so I've decided to ask for help here, maybe someone has faced this issue before?

PS: In branch.io I have notification "Your Branch and Google timezone settings do not match." but, it is only because in branch.io there is no Uzbekistan timezone. In both Adwords and Branch.io the timezones are +5 GMT.

Thank you!
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xicjY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for any inconvenience you had faced.
We checked on your integration and everything seems to be fine for Google adwords. The issue for your campaigns not being attributed here is that the device identifiers are not getting fetched for your apps and thus resulting in mis-attribution.

Requesting you to recheck on the SDK integration as per our docs here : https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/native-sdks-overview .
This should resolve your issue.